# How many fake examples are required for training a GAN?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I recently trained a GAN with ~1000 real images and 64 fake images. This obviously wasn't enough fake images, so most of the "latent space" in the GAN just creates the same image. How many fake images are GANs usually trained with in order to make their latent space usable?

Comment: What exactly do you refer to as fake images?

Answer (score 0):

The number of fake images that you generate depends on the size of the noise vector that you sample. Ideally, in a single step of training, you would sample a noise vector of dimension `batch_size x noise_dim` and use the generator to generate `batch_size` fake images. Similarly, your discriminator would see the `batch_size` number of real images.

This way, at every step, your discriminator sees an equal number of fake and real images, and the total number of fake images seen by your discriminator would be equal to the total number of images in your training set itself.